# React axios data and multi component search

Tags: ajax, reactjs, axios

Hi I am using axios to fetch JSON data in React, the issue is that I am not able to search within the fetched data.

I tried fetching the data in the parent component but the request is asynchronous so it loads child components first and then fetches data.

Below is my code :

```
  axios.get("/url.json")
    .then(function(result) {
      teams= result.data.teams
  });

ReactDOM.render(
<div>
  <App teams={teams}/>
</div>
,document.getElementById('app')
)
```

If I fetch data using axios inside the child component how do I save the data for search? i.e I need to search in the unfiltered data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `ReactDOM.render` after request succeeding : I mean inside the callback of axios NOT out side.

```
 axios.get("/url.json")
    .then(function(result) {
      const teams= result.data.teams;
      ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
         <App teams={teams}/>
        </div>
       ,document.getElementById('app')
     )
  });
```

..... OR.....

As BEST PRACTICES, you can add another layer (super-parent) which handles this call inside its **componentDidMount**    :

```
class Root extends React.Component {

   constructor() {
     super(...arguments);
     this.state= {teams : []};
   }
   componentDidMount() {
     axios.get("/url.json")
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({teams: result.data.teams})
      });
   }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <App teams={this.state.teams}/>
        </div>
     )
   }


}

 ReactDOM.render(
    <Root />
   ,document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use parent component then wont it render child component first before axios finishes fetching data?

Comment: That's why I use `this.setState`, since `setState` re-renders the content.  Try it then let's see

Comment: I tried that , child component doesn't update shows an empty list, I have used getInitialState to set the child components state from parents props.

Comment: Ok got that getInitialstate gets invoked only once when component is created, so I have used componentWillRecieveProps method.